# Can I download only the desired portion of data in the form of a csv file from the Agensgraph?

Tags: graph-databases, agens-graph

I am using Agensgraph. I want to download the data I want in the form of a csv file through the cypher syntax. Please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I could use this query to get the data I wanted in the csv file.

`agens -d Database_name -c  "CREATE TEMP TABLE File_name AS select * from(Cypher_sql) t1 ;" -c "COPY File_name TO 'File_directory/File_name.csv' DELIMITER '|' "`